# "Application Stopped Unexpectedly" error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, android-virtual-device

I'm a newbie to android developing so please bear with me and help me to solve this problem thanx so much in advance..

When i run my app on emulator splash screen is working properly but right after that when next layout should displayed pops up a message "Application Stopped Unexpectedly"
Every time i run the app same result splash works perfectly but right after that the error message.

I deleted & recreated AVD, cleaned the project,restarted the eclipse,machine but nothing....

---

**additional info if it helps**

At 1st I created project targeting Google API 14  & min SDK 8 but i had trouble with running the emulator it got stuck with only a black screen so later recreated AVD and changed target SDK to Google API 8 (projrct->properties->Android->Google API 8->apply->ok) and with min SDK 4.

---

This is MainActivity (splash screen)

```
 package com.example.GPS;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.kclogo);

    MediaPlayer mpsplash = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.startup_tone);
    mpsplash.start();

    Thread logoTimer=new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {           
            try
            {
                int logoTimer=0;

                while(logoTimer<3499)
                {
                    sleep(100);
                    logoTimer= logoTimer +100;
                }

                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.GPS.KCLOGO"));

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start();  
}
}
```

---

This is MenuActivity

```
  package com.example.GPS;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.media.MediaPlayer;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;

     public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.buttonclick);

        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.GPS.LOGIN"));
                mpButtonClick.start();

            }
        });

       }

       }
```

---

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.GPS"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.GPS.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


     <activity
        android:name="com.example.GPS.MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.GPS.KCLOGO" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    //sorry didn't include it to the question at first

   <activity
        android:name="com.example.GPS.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.GPS.LOGIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 </application>

</manifest>
```

---

### LogCat

```
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307): java.lang.**RuntimeException**:Unable to start    activity ComponentInfo{com.example.GPS/com.example.GPS.MenuActivity}: java.lang.**NullPointerException**
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307): Caused by: java.lang.**NullPointerException**
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at com.example.GPS.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:21)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at android.app.Instrumentation.**callActivityOnCreate**(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-27 22:29:14.031:E/AndroidRuntime(307):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

---

### console

```
[2013-02-27 22:28:25 - GPSTracker] Android Launch!
[2013-02-27 22:28:25 - GPSTracker] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-27 22:28:25 - GPSTracker] Performing com.example.GPS.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-02-27 22:28:25 - GPSTracker] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'GMD'
[2013-02-27 22:28:25 - GPSTracker] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'GMD'
[2013-02-27 22:28:27 - GPSTracker] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-02-27 22:28:27 - GPSTracker] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-02-27 22:28:50 - GPSTracker] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-02-27 22:28:50 - GPSTracker] Uploading GPSTracker.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-02-27 22:28:52 - GPSTracker] Installing GPSTracker.apk...
[2013-02-27 22:29:07 - GPSTracker] Success!
[2013-02-27 22:29:07 - GPSTracker] Starting activity com.example.GPS.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-02-27 22:29:08 - GPSTracker] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.GPS/.MainActivity }
```

---

login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/layoutbg" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.45" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/login_pic" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvuserid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="User ID"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etuserid"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="@drawable/gradiant" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvpass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etpass"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.42"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:background="@drawable/gradiant" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnlogin"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/padlock"
            android:text="Login" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.04"
                android:src="@drawable/exclamation" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnsignup"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:background="@color/layoutbg"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

     </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

---

kclogo.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:background="@color/layoutbg">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/kclogo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

menu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/layoutbg" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/gpscollage" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginsignup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/thumb_up_icon"
            android:text="Login/Sign Up" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addnewtomap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add_to_map"
            android:text="Add Member/s To Map" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addnewtocontacts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add_contact_list"
            android:text="Add To Contact List" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which line is line 21 in MenuActivity.java?

Comment: Make sure Button `btnlogin` exists in your layout xml.

Comment: im also not able to find `com.example.GPS.LOGIN` action inside Manifast file. make sure you are using right Action for starting Activity on button click

Comment: I think btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()... is line 21

Comment: @I2Believe - Providing we both know how to count, yes it is. btn1 is probably null

Comment: oh im sorry i didnt add them to the question silly me..

Comment: @JohnBoker You should post that as the answer, it cannot be anything else.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=" com.example.GPS.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=" com.example.GPS.LOGIN" />
these were all in manifest 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: what i ment was it was already in manifest when error occured i didnt include it to the question.. sorry for the trouble

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. It's unreadable.

Comment: @dymmeh umm could you kindly explain it to me what do you mean by btn1 is null..

Comment: @Sam Just posted the answer, I dont see what else it could be either.  I2Believe: post the contents of your layout/menu.xml

Comment: @JohnBoker i added the layout/menu.xml

Comment: I dont see `btnlogin` in the menu.xml file you provided.  That's what the error is.

Comment: @JohnBoker UR AWESOME !!!! u're right i mixed up since i had 2 login buttons i should have added signuplogin.btnlogin is not in menu.xml its in login.xml tnx so much again...
tnx every one for ur time and effort..appreciate it...

Comment: That's what we're here for :)  just don't forget to mark the answer below as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure Button `btnlogin` exists in your layout xml.

The layout you're using in the MenuActivity is main.xml, and you're looking in main.xml for btnlogin, which doesnt exist.  btn1 is null because it doesnt exist in the layout.

Comment: Congratulations on breaking 25k.

Comment: @Sam  it was harder than usual today to get a few rep to cross that threshold... Thanks!